# Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType

Tags: asp.net

I modified the codes in the ready form but when running the program it works but when registering or adding a new user from Facebook this message appears

code User Application =User_

```
public class User_ : User, IUser<int>

    {public ICollection<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; internal set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(CustomManager manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Id", this.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer32));
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public static CustomManager CreateAsync(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new CustomManager(new CustomStore(context.Get<DataContext>()));
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User_, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
         public static SignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<SignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new SignInManager(context.GetUserManager<CustomManager>(), context.Authentication);}}}
```

and I create page have Custom store

```
public async Task CreateAsync(User_ user)
        {            _context.Users.Add(user);
            _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this code ExternalLoginConfirmation

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            var user = new User_{ UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
```